# Can't start service using uwsgi in service file in centos

Tags: centos, services, uwsgi

I am trying to start a service for my flask application using `.service` file :

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to server comission project
Requires = network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/schirag/Desktop/comission_project/Hello.py
WorkingDirectory=/home/schirag/Desktop/comission_project
User=schirag
Environment="PATH=/home/schirag/Desktop/comission_project/venv/bin"


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I used this service file, the application was running fine. However when I changed my `ExecStart` to run the service using the `uwsgi`. I changed `ExecStart` to this - `/home/schirag/Desktop/comission_project/venv/bin/uwsgi --master --workers 20 --socket 0.0.0.0:9606 --protocol=http -w wsgi:application`, I am getting Active:failed, code-exited,status:203.

Comment: Does the command work outside of the service? Have you looked at the logs?

Comment: the fact that the thing points to a folder called `venv` suggests you can't call things from there without setting up the enverinment – that's the point of a `venv`.

Comment: @NasirRiley Yes it is working outside of the service